# Algorithm design manual solution to 1-8

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently reading through The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven S. Skiena.  Some of the concepts in the book I haven't used in almost 7 years.  Even while I was in college it was difficult for me to understand how some of my classmates came up with some of these proofs.  Now, I'm completely stuck on one of the exercises.  Please help.

Will you please answer this question and explain how you came up with what to use for your Base case and why each step proves why it is valid and correct.  I know this might be asking a lot, but I really need help understanding how to do these.

Thank you in advance!

Proofs of Correctness
Question:

1-8. Proove the correctness of the following algorithm for evaluating a polynomial.
$$P(x) = a_nx_n+a_n−1x_n−1+⋯+a_1x+a_0$$

```
&function horner(A,x)
  p=A_n
  for i from n−1 to 0
          p=p∗x+Ai
  return p$
```

btw, off topic: Sorry guys, I'm not sure how to correctly add the mathematical formatting for the formula.  I tried by addign '$' around each section.  Not sure why that isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure why I am being down-voted.  Please let me know why and I will try to improve my next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cs.stackexchange.com/ is probably better for this. Also I'm pretty sure that $$ formatting only works on some StackExchange sites. But anyways, think about what this algorithm is doing at each step.

We start with `p = A_n`.

Then we take `p = p*x + A_{n-1}`. So what is this doing? We now have `p = x*A_n + A_{n-1}`.

I'll try one more step. `p = p*x + A_{n-2}` so now `p = (x^2)*A_n + x*A_{n-1} + A{n-2}` (here `x^2` means x to the power 2, of course).

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you for you're help.  I see where your going.  That helped a lot!  Do you know if this would be the correct answer? 

Base case: `A = 0; x = 1`
`horner(0,1) = 0` is correct

Proof by induction
`P(x) = (A_n+1)x + (A_n)`
Next iteration would give us: `P(x) = ((A_n+1)x + (A_n))x + A_n-1`
After multiplying x through the equation we get `P(x) = ((A_n+1)x^2 + (A_n)x + A_n-1` Which equals the polynomial equations given above. 
**Q.E.D**